# Magento2.3: How to customise the default search design in home page?

Tags: magento2.3, css, search, phtml

I want to customise the default search button in home page. We have the search as below screenshot and want to do that if we click the search icon it should open the input box below the search icon.

[image]

How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript.
Add a click function to the search-icon-button.
Search Google for "javascript show elements"

Next:
Find the correct file to edit:

```
CMS > Debug > Profiler > Paths
```

You will see the path to the files to edit.

Hope this helps.